# Simple example of consuming wsdl webservice with Java?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm trying to consume a WSDL webservice in Java, in what will eventually be an Eclipse plugin.

I can use File>New>Other to select "Web Service Client" which works, but it generates a bunch of files that would have to changed/regenerated when the webservice changes, which is rather rubbish.

Everywhere I look I'm seeing assorted ways of doing things, but I can't get any of them to actually do what I want.

Here's some code:

```
String WsdlUrl = "http://localhost:port/path/to/wsdl";

ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList();
args.add("arg1");
args.add("arg2");
// etc

Webservice ws = setupWebserviceObject( WsdlUrl );
Object result = ws.invoke("methodname",args);

System.out.println(result);
```

Basically what I need is to change "Webservice", "setupWebserviceObject", and "invoke" into whatever works, without needing pre-generated classes and with a minimum of any other annoying fluff.

It doesn't seem like it should be difficult to do, but so far I've not found a clear example of how to do it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I am also looking in to same issue..did you got solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

I suppose the concept of "simple" is incompatible with all things WSDL but here are some examples:

- [Creating a dynamic web service client from WSDL using JAX-WS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_jaxwsdynclient.html).
- [Creating a web service client using the Apache Axis2 Axiom API](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html#clientaxiom).

**[Note] I've kept the original, misunderstood response below, in case it helps anyone.**

This article is a good summary of your options for implementing a service from WSDL:
[*5 Techniques for Creating Java Web Services from WSDL*](http://java.dzone.com/news/5-techniques-create-web-servic).

The JAX-WS Provider API implementation might be the easiest route if you are using Java 6+.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading it, that page is about **creating a new webservice** in Java? That is not what I need.

  I am asking what the Java code to **consume an existing webservice** is.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I thought your were looking to implement a webservice from WSDL, not consume it.

Comment: I guess the "createWebservice" in the question could have been confusing - I've renamed it to "setupWebserviceObject" instead.

Comment: WSDL consumption is simple. Using other tools, for other programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way step by step:

This was made using Apache CXF and Maven dependency management.

1 - Get the WSDL descriptor of the service saved in a file. Put it in the resources folder of your project (folder should be in the Source folders list of your project, if you are using eclipse).

2 - In the pom.xml declare the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

3 -  Use following Maven plugin to generate the java classes:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                    <wsdlOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>${basedir}/resources/WebService.wsdl.xml</wsdl>
                        </wsdlOption>
                    </wsdlOptions>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

4 - Use following code to make the call:

```
String methodName = "getSomethingFromMyWebService";
DynamicClientFactory dcf = DynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = dcf.createClient(ConsumeTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("WebService.wsdl.xml"));

Object[] res = client.invoke(methodName,parameter1,parameter2, parameterN);
SomethingObject[] somethingObjectList = (SomethingObject[])res[0];
Class.forName(res.getClass().getName()).isArray();
for(SomethingObject so : somethingObjectList){
    // do something!
}
```

5 - Profit!

Notes: If the method does not return a list of something you have to cast to the object it returns instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using axis2 command line tools, most simply:

> java2wsdl -cn fully-qualified-class-name
>
> wsdl2java -uri wsdlLocation -ss -sd -uw -g -o outputLocation

`cd` into `outputLocation` and run ant

Put generated `.aar` file to `WEB-INF/services` folder to create service (dont need if you just want client) and copy generated stub files to your source folder. You can use `YourServiceSkeleton` class to implement business logic and use `YourServiceStub` class for the client